# How to test if connection is ok in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I tried

```
if (DB::connection()) { 
    //
}
```

but this produces error :

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I want to test from code if everything is fine with connection but without errors,
I am looking for solution without try catch.....

Comment: That means the username and password combination used to login into the MySQL server is incorrect. Check the username and password values in your `.env` file.

Comment: I know that username and password are wrong, I need code to test if username and password are wrong or not ...

Comment: Why no try/catct? It's a good scenario to use it

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20521737/how-to-check-if-connected-to-database-in-laravel-4

Comment: vijaykumar it is not duplicated, I am looking for solution without error, solution from your url produces PDOException error if connection is not fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Luke pointed out, your one of best possible options is using try and catch.

```
try{
    Schema::hasTable('mytable');
    // or \DB::statement('show Databases');
}catch(\PDOException $e){
    //This means there is definitely error connecting to database
    //I don't understand why you don't want to catch me :(
}
```

you can use the above code in a helper function or trait or any sane idea of your choice.
Other possibilities are using `shell_exec()` or `system()` etc

Answer (score 0):

just do simple artisan command.

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

Comment: Actually I think this in an elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code in a try catch statement, so that you can catch the exception and then output a nicer message, or redirect somewhere else.

For reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: It is not exception, I want to test if connection is ok, like I can test if table exists:
Schema::hasTable('some_table')